# Count Items in an Array of Arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift

If I have an object that is declared as

```
let compoundArray = [Array<String>]
```

is there a property that would give me the number of strings in all the arrays contained in compoundArray?

I can do it by adding up all the items in each array within:

```
var totalCount = 0
for array in compoundArray {
   totalCount += array.count }
//totalCount = total items in all arrays within compoundArray
```

But that seems clunky and it seems that swift would have a property/method of Array to do this, no?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `joined` or `flatMap` for that.

**Using `joined`**

```
let count = compoundArray.joined().count
```

**Using `flatMap`**

```
let count = compoundArray.flatMap({$0}).count
```

Comment: why when i create array in this way var arr = Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: Array(count: 2, repeatedValue: "String")) count of the elements is wrong with flatMap approach ?

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk that is not valid Swift 3 syntax. For `var arr = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: "String", count: 2), count: 3)` we correctly get a total count of 6 using the `flatMap` approach.

Comment: @NiravD my bad I look at the count of the iterations not in the actual result. Number of iteration was 4 but count is 6

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk It's ok :)

Comment: Of these two methods, `joined` might be preferable because it returns a "view" on the flattened collection, whereas `flatMap` creates a new array.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 19):

You can add the nested array counts with

```
let count = compoundArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.count }
```

Performance comparison for *large* arrays (compiled and run on a MacBook Pro in Release configuration):

```
let N = 20_000
let compoundArray = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: "String", count: N), count: N)

do {
    let start = Date()
    let count = compoundArray.joined().count
    let end = Date()
    print(end.timeIntervalSince(start))
    // 0.729196012020111
}

do {
    let start = Date()
    let count = compoundArray.flatMap({$0}).count
    let end = Date()
    print(end.timeIntervalSince(start))
    // 29.841913998127
}

do {
    let start = Date()
    let count = compoundArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.count }
    let end = Date()
    print(end.timeIntervalSince(start))
    // 0.000432014465332031
}
```

Comment: Is this approach is suitable to count elements in the 2d arrays ?

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk: There are no 2D arrays in Swift. If you mean "nested arrays" then this should work (and Nirav's solutions as well).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are asking for a *property*, I thought I'd point out how to create one (for all collections, while we're at it):

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Collection {
    var flatCount: Int {
        return self.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.count } // as per Martin R
    }
}
```

Making this recursive seems to be an [interesting exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41640321/539599).